# How can I accurately estimate the current btc network fees using bitcoinlib 0.6.10 in python?

Tags: python, bitcoinlib

How to estimate btc network fees with python bitcoinlib 0.6.10.

From bitcoinlib docs, I have found 2 ways to retrieve current network fees via service providers.

`fees_sato = service.estimatefee(blocks=3, priority='low')`

However, why is it that:
1- The fees are always way higher than any current btc network fees estimator websites?
2- Sometimes the estimate generated with `priority='low'` is higher than the one generated with `priority='high' ?

Tried both ways and the result seems to be inaccurate.
I want to retrieve an accurate estimate of the current btc network fees.

Comment: I think I found what my problem was.
service.estimatefee(blocks=3, priority='low')
returns a the fee value in sats PER KB and I think most btc transactions are less than 1kb